# How to make it shorter - Java String.equal(string) method

Tags: java, if-statement

I made if statement, but it is so long..

like that :

```
if("WORDS".equals(object.string1) || "WORDS".equals(object.string2) || "WORDS".equals(object.string3)
|| "WORDS".equals(object.string4) || "WORDS".equals(object.string5) || "WORDS".equals(object.string6)
|| "WORDS".equals(object.string7) || "WORDS".equals(object.string8)  || "WORDS".equals(object.string9)
|| "WORDS".equals(object.string10)) { ......... }
```

how to make it shorter statement

Comment: Put `string1..string10` into a `Set<String>`, and use `set.contains("WORDS")`.

Comment: With your edit, you've now made it either not compile (since `java.lang.Object` doesn't have those fields) or confusing (since `Object` no longer refers to `java.lang.Object`).

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't make any sense. Do you have any actual (compilable) code to ask about?

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the OP was going for a more plastic explanation. If it said `MyClass` instead of `Object` it would've made more sense but still wouldn't compile.

Comment: Put `string1..string10` into a first place (numbered variable names are always suspicious), and then use `Arrays.asList(strings).contains("WORDS")`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Already using that if statement

Comment: @khelwood why doen't mde sence? I am using it...

Comment: @Ryujihoon Made less sense at the time of my comment, before it was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function with variable number of arguments:

```
static bool compareMultiStrings(String words, String ... stringi) {
  if (words == null) return false;

  for(String  s : stringi){
    if (words.equals(s)) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

and then call it from your if:

```
if (
  compareMultiStrings(
    "WORDS",
    object.string1, object.string2, object.string3, object.string4,
    object.string5, object.string6, object.string7, object.string8,
    object.string9)
)
{ ..... }
```

The first argument if for your constants string, `"WORDS"`.  The other parameters is the varargs parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
static boolean equalsOr(String a, String... b) {
    for (String s : b)
        if (a.equals(s))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

and

```
if (equalsOr("WORDS", object.string1, object.string2, ...))
```